# How can I popScene a specific Cocos2D scene from another scene?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game that I developed, and there are three scenes: the pause menu, the home screen menu, and the gameplay itself. During the gameplay, when the game is paused, it brings up the pause scene with:

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[PauseScene node]];`

From the pause scene, there are three options: restart, resume, home menu. When clicking on resume it just pops the pause scene and goes back to the game scene to resume gameplay. When clicking on the home menu it keeps the gameplay scene in the background, and from the home menu screen, the gameplay is still running. So far, after much research, I have not been able to find a way to popScene (kick it out of the RAM pretty much) the gameplay scene from any scene but the gameplay scene. From the pause screen, I can use:

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];`

to get rid of the pause scene, and if I run that code from a method on the gameplay scene, I can get rid of that instance of gameplay, but I need a way to popScene the gameplay node that is running in the background from the pause node. Overall, the basic question is: How can I pop a specific scene in Cocos2d from another scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main features to change scenes in Cocos2d:  `pushScene`/`popScene` and `replaceScene`.

1. The first is `pushScene`:

> - (void) pushScene:       (CCScene *)     scene
>
> Suspends the execution of the running scene, pushing it on the stack
>   of suspended scenes. The new scene will be executed. Try to avoid big
>   stacks of pushed scenes to reduce memory allocation. ONLY call it if
>   there is a running scene.

This function utilizes a [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249948/explanation-of-how-stacks-work-in-c) .  It stores all the scenes in a [Last In-First Out (LIFO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29) data structure.  Basically it overlays the scenes and removes them in the reverse order of which they came.  This is likely what you want to "push" (or bring up) the pause menu, and "pop" (remove) the pause scene back off to then resume gameplay.

To go back a layer, you simply call `popScene`:

> - (void) popScene
>
> Pops out a scene from the queue. This scene will replace the running
>   one. The running scene will be deleted. If there are no more scenes in
>   the stack the execution is terminated. ONLY call it if there is a
>   running scene.

2.The other option, which I believe you will want, is `replaceScene`.  This stops a currently running scene and replaces it with a completely new one.  This is likely what you want for ending games or transitioning from the original main menu to the gameplay for the first time:

> - (void) replaceScene:        (CCScene *)     scene
>
> Replaces the running scene with a new one. The running scene is
>   terminated. ONLY call it if there is a running scene

*Keep in mind:  Use `pushScene` sparingly.  It stores all of the scenes in memory so that they can later be popped of the stack.  So don't store too many scenes and forget about them.

**Source: [cocos2D website](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0-rc/interface_c_c_director.html#a548727f4d1521265d32abc2916f72f55)

EDIT 1:

You have a few options.  Remember that `replaceScene` only replaces the currently running scene and is usually what you want to use.  It does not "clear" the entire scene stack, so often you rarely want to use `pushScene`/`popScene`.  In my demo below, I show you the issues with both.  I do, however, try to conserve memory by when possible.

Using push/popScene:

1.Start running with the Home Screen.

2.When the user clicks "Play" button, use `replaceScene` to stop the Home Screen scene and start running the Game Play scene (keep in mind, Home Screen will no longer be running or saved anywhere in memory.  if it has to remember any information, then save it to the stack with `pushScene`.  The reason I do this is because the Home Screen will likely be the same each time and needs not continue to run while we play).

3.The user can now play for a bit.  Then they want to pause for a bathroom break.  They click a "Pause" button.  Then use `pushScene` to save the current state of Game Play scene and begin running the Pause Menu scene.  (Game Play is "paused" so to speak).
  Your stack now looks like this:

`//Bottom  ---------------------->  Top`

`[Game Play scene], [Pause Menu Scene]`

4.After pausing for a bit, they could use `pushScene` to remove Pause Menu Scene from memory, and load the Game Play scene that is "paused" and resume play immediately.

The problem then becomes, well, what if you wanted to go from pause -> main menu.  If you just used `replaceScene` on the Pause Menu, then the old game would linger in memory.  You would need to find a way to purge that old Game Play scene.

The other option would have to be keeping Home Screen around by keeping it on the stack with a `pushScene` and then popping twice.  This often causes "jumpy" transitions from my experience.

The preferred approach tends to be: create a [Singleton Class](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?344782-C-Design-Pattern-What-is-a-Singleton-class) and have that save the memory while you pause.  (A Singleton Class is just a class that only ever has one instance.  It is basically our "current game state" data.  I recommend this t[utorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager).)

Using Replace Scene:

1.Start running with the Home Screen.

2.When the user clicks "Play" button, use `replaceScene` to stop the Home Screen scene and start running the Game Play scene (keep in mind, Home Screen will no longer be running or saved anywhere in memory.  if it has to remember any information, then have a section of the `Singleton Class` for Home Screen data).

3.The user can now play for a bit.  Then they want to pause for a bathroom break.  They click a "Pause" button.  Immediately "pause" your game and save all necessary sprites, game logic, etc to the `Singleton Class`, and then use `replaceScene` to quit from the Game Play scene and load Pause Scene.  Then depending on their choice, you either continue play (step 4), or go to the Home Screen(step 5)

4.Reload everything necessary to render the game from the `Singleton Class` and `replaceScene` to quit from the Pause Menu and load up Game Play scene.

5.Use `replaceScene` to quit from the Pause Menu and load up the Home Screen.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how all of the different scene changes work, but I still need to know how to pop one specific scene from another scene.

Comment: Could you show me the order of scenes you want to run?  "pop" doesn't change scene.  It merely removes the last "push" and resumes the most prior scene before that "push" that is still running (and temporarily stored in memory).

Comment: Home Screen-> GamePlay-> Pause-> Home Screen
The problem is that I need to kick the gameplay scene that was suspended in the background from the pause screen. It continues to run in the background of the last Home Screen in the flow chart.

Comment: Thank you, I will be back in a few minutes then.

Comment: I updated it.  I'm still doing some proof-reading and cleaning up.  But it should hopefully answer your question.  If this is unclear or not exactly what you were looking for, then let me know!

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be exactly what I am looking for, but I have never worked with Singleton classes before in anything I have developed. Do you have any code or resources that could possibly show me how to implement a singleton class to do what is mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I would check out the following guide: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager (also gonna add this to the answer).  You have a few options including: NSCoding and using files with NSFileManager.

Comment: there's also popToRootScene: and popToSceneStackLevel: